# どこからか、バイオリンの(a.音色　b.コーラス)が聞こえてきた。

Tags: word-choice

I am learning Japanese N1 and found this question

> どこからか、バイオリンの(a.音色　b.コーラス)が聞こえてきた。

Which one do you think is correct ? a or b ?

Answer (score 2):

The correct choice is 音色. In Japanese, コーラス normally refers to 合唱 or group singing, so バイオリンのコーラス doesn't make much sense. (Experts of music may say something different, though.)